# How to populate Quote data in form fields?

Tags: magento2

```
 $fieldset->addField(
        'first_name',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'FirstName',
            'label' => __('First Name'),
            'id' => 'FirstName',
            'title' => __('First Name'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'input-text',
            'data-validate' => '{"required":true, "validate-FirstName":true}',
            'value' => $firstname // Set default value
        ]
    );
```

Comment: I will share my discord id "mohit_gento" so can we chat on this? I will help for you.

Comment: ok sure please .

Comment: I will share the code you want so please check it. l

Answer (score 0):

hello if you can follow the below link without UI component created grid.

https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-create-admin-grid-and-form-without-ui-component/

if you want a new column then follow the below step.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Rh/Blog/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Edit/Tab/Main.php

open this file after blog title add below code

```
<?php

 namespace Rh\Blog\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;


class Main extends Generic implements TabInterface
{

/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
 */
protected $_adminSession;

/**
 * @var \Rh\Blog\Model\Status
 */
protected $_status;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry             $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory     $formFactory
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session     $adminSession
 * @param \Rh\Blog\Model\Status                   $status
 * @param array                                   $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession,
    \Rh\Blog\Model\Status $status,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_adminSession = $adminSession;
    $this->_status = $status;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare the form.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('rh_blog_form_data');

    $isElementDisabled = false;

    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Blog Information')]);

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'name',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => __('Name'),
            'title' => __('Name'),
            'required' => true,
            'value' => $this->_adminSession->getUser()->getFirstname(),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'title',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'title',
            'label' => __('Blog Title'),
            'title' => __('Blog Title'),
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
        ]
    );

      $fieldset->addField(
        'first_name',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'first_name',
            'label' => __('FirstName'),
            'title' => __('FirstName'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'letters-only'
           ]
         );

    $contentField = $fieldset->addField(
        'content',
        'textarea',
        [
            'name' => 'content',
            'label' => __('Content'),
            'title' => __('Content'),
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
        ]
    );

    $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);

    $fieldset->addField(
        'status',
        'select',
        [
            'label' => __('Status'),
            'title' => __('Status'),
            'name' => 'status',
            'required' => true,
            'options' => $this->_status->getOptionArray(),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
        ]
    );

    if (!$model->getId()) {
        $model->setData('status', $isElementDisabled ? '0' : '1');
    }

    $form->addValues($model->getData());
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

/**
 * Return Tab label
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('Blog Information');
}

/**
 * Return Tab title
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('Blog Information');
}

/**
 * Can show tab in tabs
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Tab is hidden
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Check permission for passed action
 *
 * @param string $resourceId
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
}
}
```

created a db_schema.xml file to add a column in your table.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Rh/Blog/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
<table name="rh_blog">
    <column name="first_name" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar" comment="Customer Note" length="255"/>
</table>
```

if you want your column to show the grid, change the file below.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Rh/Blog/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Grid.php

```
<?php

namespace Rh\Blog\Block\Adminhtml\Grid;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

/**
 * @var \Rh\Blog\Model\Status
 */
protected $_status;

/**
 * @var \Rh\Blog\Model\BlogFactory
 */
protected $_blogFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
 */
protected $moduleManager;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data            $backendHelper
 * @param \Rh\Blog\Model\BlogFactory              $blogFactory
 * @param \Rh\Blog\Model\Status                   $status
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager       $moduleManager
 * @param array                                   $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
    \Rh\Blog\Model\BlogFactory $blogFactory,
    \Rh\Blog\Model\Status $status,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_blogFactory = $blogFactory;
    $this->_status = $status;
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('gridGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setVarNameFilter('grid_record');
}

/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_blogFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    $this->addColumn(
        'id',
        [
            'header' => __('ID'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'id',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'name',
        [
            'header' => __('Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'title',
        [
            'header' => __('Title'),
            'index' => 'title',
        ]
    );

     $this->addColumn(
        'first_name',
        [
            'header' => __('First Name'),
            'index' => 'first_name',
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'status',
        [
            'header' => __('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->_status->getOptionArray(),
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'created_at',
        [
            'header' => __('Created At'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'edit',
        [
            'header' => __('Edit'),
            'type' => 'action',
            'getter' => 'getId',
            'actions' => [
                [
                    'caption' => __('Edit'),
                    'url' => [
                        'base' => 'blog/*/edit',
                    ],
                    'field' => 'id',
                ],
            ],
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'index' => 'stores',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-action',
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'delete',
        [
            'header' => __('Delete'),
            'type' => 'action',
            'getter' => 'getId',
            'actions' => [
                [
                    'caption' => __('Delete'),
                    'url' => [
                        'base' => 'blog/*/delete',
                    ],
                    'field' => 'id',
                ],
            ],
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'index' => 'stores',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-action',
        ]
    );

    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');

    if ($block) {
        $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
    }

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('id');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
        'delete',
        [
            'label' => __('Delete'),
            'url' => $this->getUrl('blog/*/massDelete'),
            'confirm' => __('Are you sure?'),
        ]
    );

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('blog/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('blog/*/edit', ['id' => $row->getId()]);
}
}
```

I will share the below screenshot so you can see your column.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

i hope that is help for you. so please accept my answer and upvote me.

Comment: Hi mohit vamja thanks for your answer dear

Comment: i have created grid and form now i just want to populate data in a form

Comment: i will share my discord id "mohit_gento". can we chat on them?